# Simple React Snippets not showing in side bar

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am following "Mosh course for react" and installed Simple React Snippets but its not showing in side bar

This is a VS Code Issue mainly

Both mine and Mosh pics attached

Mine:
[image]

Instructors (Mosh):
[image]

Comment: You don't have the folder open

Comment: Please post code showing what you achieved so far and eventual error messages. So that one can point what problem is happening and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on file, then open folder, navigate to the folder location of the project and select the folder for the project.

Answer (score 0):

"Simple react snippets" is an extension available on vs code. You won't see it in folder structure you .
If you want to open you project in vs-code then go to the folder where you created the project -> open cmd there -> type "code ."  and your project will open in vs code.

Comment: if this helped you please mark it as useful (tick mark sign) . Feel free to ask more questions too